# Project image on uv sphere (for pool balls)

Tags: uv

I'd like to create pool balls. There are several balls with different colors and numbers. There should be only 1 model with various textures which can be edited in a 2d image application.

Example:

[image]

I'd like to put a ribbon like this on the blue area:

[image]

Is there a way (uv projection?) which allows me to project that flat ribbon on the sphere So that it'll look similar to this in the end:

[image]

Comment: Do you want one texture for all or a texture for each ball type? Which render engine do you aim to use?

Comment: Multiple textures which can be applied to 1 ball model. I'd like to use it in Unity.

Comment: Or in other words: I'd like to simply change the color and the text for each ball in Photoshop.

Comment: @Roland - I edited my answer with a better node set up for a material closer to your sample image. Sorry for any confusion... Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the **Cycles** Render Engine.

Create a UV Sphere > Shift +”A” > Choose “Mesh” > “Sphere” from the drop down menu.

While still in Object Mode > Shading > Smooth from the Tool Bar (Press “T” to toggle it on/off). Also press CTRL + “A” and apply the Scale. (You can also add a Subdivision Surface Modifier).

[image: Create Sphere]

In the Materials Tab create a new material.

In the Node Editor create your node set up. Including your image texture with an Alpha channel. I used a .PNG with an alpha channel image file.

[image: Node Set Up]

**EDIT:**
I realized the the stripe (purple area)did not have any gloss so I've added an additional node set up for that.

Also I took out some roughness in the Gloss Nodes / Added  slight blur to the Image Texture / Added a slight bit of yellow and red to the white part of the ball.[image: Improved node set up]

Go into UV Editing Mode press TAB to go into Edit Mode and select all > Press “U” and select “Sphere Projection” from the drop down menu.

Select “Texture” and you will be able to see a preview of your texture.

[image: Texture]

If the texture is stretched while still in edit mode and your cursor in the UV Editing window adjust the “X” scale of the UV Map scale by pressing “S” then “X”.

[image]

In this example in order to avoid a gap in the image texture on the back of the Sphere > in the Image Editor scale the UV Map down to fit the Texture.

[image: Render][image: Improved Render]

Comment: Questions are better than answers... Thank you.